# How to fix interceptor?

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

My interceptor work good for add access token to header and refresh tokens.
But if i brake my access and refresh token i my refresh token failed two times.
What behavior i need is when refresh token request failed in first time then i want to clear storage and redirect user to login.
But in this case my catchError inside authService.pipe works only on with second failed refresh token request
[image]

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let authReq = request;
    const token = this.storageService.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
      authReq = this.addTokenHeader(request, token);
    }
    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.handle401Error(authReq, next);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }


  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      const token = this.storageService.getRefreshToken();

      if (token) {
        return this.authService.refreshToken(token).pipe(
          switchMap((token: TokenModel) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            this.storageService.setToken(token.accessToken);
            this.storageService.setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken);
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken);

            return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token.accessToken));
          }),
          catchError((error) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            this.storageService.clearStorage();
            this.router.navigate([''])
            return throwError(error);
          }),
        );
      }
    }
    return next.handle(request)
  }

  addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)});
  }
}
```

Please help my find what i am doing wrong and how can i fix it